# In Apex 5.1, how can I open an list item that links to a page in my application in a new window in my browser?

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

looking for a way in Apex 5.1 to open list items that goes to a specific page in a new window.

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Answer (score 2):

1 - Go to your list on Shared Components

2 - On each item of your list, fill on "User Defined Attributes" the second field (image below):

[image]

Example: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:5:
Test 1 open on another page

If dont work check the correct field to put your link attributes. (image below, click on it):

[image]

Comment: I have a link on a page that I want to open in a new tab.  My question is how can I do that?  I know I have to use target=new or target=_blank but where do I put that in Apex 5.1.

Comment: How did you create this link?
If it was in a report, just use the "link attributes" field and put target="_blank".

Comment: I created the link using the list feature.   Once the link in clicked, it goes to another page in my application but I want to open the page in a new tab. there is an attributes field and alt atributes field but when I try target="_blank" it does not work.

Comment: I tried this but it still opens in the same window/tab.

Comment: So, check where is the correct place to put the link attributes of your region. check the new image on the answer.

Comment: if you created this list from classic report template, for instance, if it's a media list, you can add ,'target="_blank"' as link_attr to your query.